# How to connect in ssh to a server with ipv6

Tags: server, ssh, openssh

I am trying to connect through ssh to my VM server, and when typing ifconfig, i only find ipv6 connections. I therefore don't know how to connect to my server... 
Help ?

can i somehow still use this ?

```
ssh username@ip
```

Comment: Have you tried ?

Comment: yes. i get : connect to host <ip> port 2222: Invalid argument

Comment: I am using to connect what is written after inet6

Comment: Could you please update your question with the exact command you are trying to run ?

Comment: dang it, stupid me, i have solved it... Nevermind it was a WM Problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right, here is what i have done.
Two things: 
1) I had forgotten to use the bridged connection option. 
2) I put eth0 instead of wlan0 (i was not connected through ethernet). 
In case someone is wondering how to connect with IPv6, it is exactly the same. You just write your ip in IPv6 behind your name, like in ipv6 !

Comment: Is this an answer to your question, or some clarification?

Comment: An answer, but i must wait until tomorrow to validate it